# I need to scrape HTML table with irregular colums

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please can anyone help me, I am very new to Beautiful Soup for scraping web pages. I want to extract the first table on the webpage, however the table has irregular columns as shown in the attached image. The first 3 rows/ 3 columns is followed by a row with 1 column. Please note the first three rows can change in the future to be more or less than 3 rows. The single row/1 column is followed by some rows and 4 columns then a single row/column. Is there a way I can write the Beautiful Soup python script to extract the first 3 rows before the td tag with a columnspan of 6 then extract the next rows after the td tag with a columnspan of 6?

[image]

My Python code so far (#### gives me the entire table with the irregular column but not what I want):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = " "

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
rows = []
for child in soup.find_all('table')[1].children:
    row = []
    for td in child:
        try:
            row.append(td.text.replace('\n', ''))

        except:
             continue
    if len(row) > 0:
        rows.append(row)

pd.DataFrame(rows[1:])
```

Comment: What's the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once having the table element I would select for the tr children not having a td with colspan = 6

Here is an example with colspan 3

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<table id="foo">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">I'm not invited to the party :-(</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td>I</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.select('#foo tr:not(:has(td[colspan="3"]))'):
    print([child.text for child in tr.select('th, td')])
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr, your example gave me a clue of what I need to do, to adjust my code.